# Multiple polymorphic relations of same type in one model - MongoID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, polymorphic-associations

I couldn't figure out how to work the title correctly, so let me explain.

I have my class Like:

```
class Like
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :likable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Submission
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :submissions
  has_many :likes, :as => :likable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Then the class that causes the problem:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :submissions, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :liked_submissions, :as => :likable, :dependent => :destroy, class_name: 'Like'
  has_many :liked_comments, :as => :likable, :dependent => :destroy, class_name: 'Like'
end
```

Now, the problem is that I can't figure out how to properly have both 'liked_comments' and 'liked_comments' in the user class. When I have it as I do above I get the error: `Ambiguous relations :liked_submissions, :liked_comments defined on User.` when trying to create a like for a submission.

I looked around, and I found a Github issue that said that this may not be possible, but I can't find this issue again, and I wasn't even sure that it was related to this issue.

Is this possible, and if not, any suggestions to getting around it? I would like to use likes in a BlogPost model as well, but if this doesn't work, I'll have to find another way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this and it works using mongoid version 4.0.2:

```
class Like
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :likable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user
end

class Submission
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :submissions
  has_many :likes, as: :likable, dependent: :destroy
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :submissions, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :likes, as: :user
  has_many :liked_submissions, as: :likable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Like'
  has_many :liked_comments, as: :likable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Like'
end

class BlogPost
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :likes, as: :likable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Also `user.liked_submissions` and `user.liked_comments` are the same relation so it is equivalent to declaring an alias like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :submissions, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :likes, as: :user
  has_many :liked_submissions, as: :likable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Like'

  alias :liked_comments :liked_submissions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Had tough times after discovering this issue but got cool solution that works

**Add to your Gemfile**

> gem 'mongoid-multiple-polymorphic'

**And this works like a charm:**

```
  class Resource

  has_one :icon, as: :assetable, class_name: 'Asset', dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  has_one :preview, as: :assetable, class_name: 'Asset', dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

  end
```